# Oracle (OracleClient) data source not showing up in Visual Studio 2015 for SSRS

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, datasource, dataprovider, system.data.oracleclient

I'm currently working with SSRS 2014 reports with visual studio 2013.
We have been asked to use visual studio 2015, but I ran into an issue with the data sources missing in 2015.

In 2013 I saw the following data sources:
[image: Data sources available in Visual Studio 2013]
[image: ADO IN 2013]

In 2015 I see the following data sources:
[image: Data sources available in Visual Studio 2015]
[image: ODP IN 2015]

Is there any configuration that will allow me to use OracleClient or even show both data providers?

Comment: Which entries do you get in drop-down list of "Data provider:"? What do you mean by "OracleClient"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've added more pictures of where OracleClient is being displayed. In a short summary, OracleClient is the System.Data.OracleClient driver Microsoft created a long time ago. It has been depreciated for a while now but everyone basically still uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Registry editor and navigate to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\DataSources`, resp. `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\DataSources`

Compare the branch with `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\DataSources`, resp. `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\DataSources`

Check also keys `...\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\DataProviders`, `...\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\DataProviders`

It should be no problem to copy some entries from old Visual Studio to new version.

Comment: The registries appear to be identical. The only different value appears to be the version which is relative to the visual studio version. I tried changing it but no luck. It's still displaying the ODP data provider only.

DataSource_Oracle, SR, Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=---

DataSource_Oracle, SR, Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=---